# GMapping Performance differentiates between git package and sudo apt-get package

Tags: slam, navigation, cpu, gmapping, slam-gmapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi together,

## Edit

See answer from myself.

## Prolbem:

We are running Gmapping on our robot to map the environment but facing some really strange performance problems. (Dont be scared, I know it is an algorithm working a lot with probabilistics :) but that's not the problem ). Our problem is, Gmapping runs on our laptops pretty good, but not on our local pcs mounted to the robot which have better processors more RAM etc.. so overall a better performance

**To our setup:**

We recorded some bag files replayed them on a machine and run GMapping simultaneously.
Everything works fine on our Thinkpad T450s with an i5 5300U and 8 Gigs RAM + SSD, Ubuntu 14.04. After round about 30 seconds the Thinkpad processed already 50 scans and updated the map.

Playing the same bag file with same setup, same launch file, everthing the same on our local machine on the robot which is a fanless [ADLINK MXE5401](http://www.adlinktech.com/PD/web/PD_detail.php?pid=1318) with an i7 4600EQ (which should be a little bit stronger compared to the thinkpads cpu, on a single core since GMapping has no multicore capabilities) 16GB RAM + SSD, Ubuntu 14.04, the GMapping is only capable of processing in round about 30seconds 10 Scans. So the algorithm detects "big jumps in odometry" and isn't able to match its environment/scans to the already built map anymore.

Maybe this is just a problem I never knew before about some cpu supoort by Ubuntu or anything else, maybe some of you guys can point me to the right direction.

Thanks in advance!!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/231372/gmapping-performance-differentiates-between-git-package-and-sudo-apt-get-package/) by [schultza](https://answers.ros.org/users/18901/schultza/) on ROS Answers with karma: 232 on 2016-04-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Could be that you didn't compile with `-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release` or `RelWithDebInfo`. The binary packages are compiled with optimisations, which you otherwise don't get.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2016-04-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [schultza](https://answers.ros.org/users/18901/schultza/) on 2016-04-08**:
That did the trick!! Thanks so much!

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-04-08**:
Converted to answer for you.